# The command eval $(minikube docker-env) is not working because of error that says "Cannot connect to docker daemon"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-machine, minikube

I have started minikube using the following command

`minikube start --insecure-registry k8s.gcr.io --insecure-registry registry-1.docker.io --insecure-registry gcr.io --insecure-registry registry.gitlab.com`

After it starts I check the status using `minikube status` and the output is the following

```
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.99.107
```

Afterwards I run the command `eval $(minikube docker-env)` so that it can use the docker daemon that minikube is using.

That command runs as is expected. When I check the `DOCKER_HOST` I get the following value `tcp://192.168.99.107:2376`

The problem starts when I run a docker command.

For example, when I run `docker run hello-world`, the command will hang for a while and then I get the following output

```
docker: error during connect: Post https://192.168.99.107:2376/v1.39/containers/create: Service Unavailable.
```

One thing you might notice is that the `DOCKER_HOST` uses TCP will docker run will use HTTPS. I don't know but maybe it might help in getting this issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**HTTPS** can run over any reliable stream transport protocol. Normally that's **TCP**.

**1.** Check if your image is built.

To run docker images in Kubernetes you can simply use

`$ kubectl run hello-world --image=... --port=... --image-pull-policy=...`

But you have to set on Docker daemon as well.  More information you can find here: [`docker-daemon`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/#use-local-images-by-re-using-the-docker-daemon)

**2.** Check **2376** port if it is not already in use.

**3.** Try to run your command as root:
Run it as sudo docker ... instead of docker .... 
The user that you are running as may not have permissions to talk to /var/run/docker.sock on that system.

**4.** Which version of minikube you use ? In minikube **v0.10.0** the --insecure-registry flag is ignored if the machine already existed.). First check if --insecure-registry= is correctly copied into /var/lib/boot2docker/profile in the new VM. You must first minikube delete if you want new flags to be respected.

I hope it helps.